# Use existing connection pool with mySQL2 for Node.JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2

Does the following code create a new pool every time or will it use an existing pool if one exists?
If it creates a new one each time, what is the code to use an existing connection?

```
const pool = mysql.createPool()
```

I have not been able to find any code samples for using existing connection.

Comment: A pool is used to reuse connections. It's all documented [here](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools).

Comment: It creates a new pool every time. Use `pool.getConnection()` to get a connection from the pool. I wrote a small guide for people new to MySQL and Node. Hope it's helpful: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Comment: Robert. I am extremally familiar with the documentation. I do not see anywhere on that page where my question is answered or addressed. If I missed it can I trouble you to call out the specific code on that page?